# the value of id = 1 always laravel

Tags: laravel, orm

No matter which question you try to access, this, the value of the id that returns is id = 1 and question_id = 1, for example

```
/exams/1/questions/5/answers
```

`web.php`

```
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers               | exams.questions.answers.index   | App\Http\Controllers\AnswerController@index
         | web        |
|        |           |                                                         |                                 |
         | auth       |
|        | POST      | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers               | exams.questions.answers.store   | App\Http\Controllers\AnswerController@store
         | web        |
|        |           |                                                         |                                 |
         | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD  | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/create        | exams.questions.answers.create  | App\Http\Controllers\AnswerController@create
         | web        |
|        |           |                                                         |                                 |
         | auth       |
|        | PUT|PATCH | exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers/{answer}      | exams.questions.answers.update  | App\Http\Controllers\AnswerController@update
```

On this route I have no answer. However, this returns me.

```
{
"id": 1,
"question_id": 1,
"description": "Descripcion suprema",
"iframe": "iframe.chido.mp4",
"image": null,
"is_correct": 0,
"created_at": "2020-08-29T22:33:28.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-08-29T22:33:28.000000Z"
},
```

Relations on my models

Question

```
class Question extends Model{
  protected $fillable = [
    'exam_id', 'category_id' ,'description', 'iframe', 'image',
  ];
  public function answers(){
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class,'answer_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

Answer

```
class Answer extends Model{
  protected $fillable = [
      'question_id', 'description', 'iframe', 'image', 'is_correct'
  ];

  public function question(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Question::class, 'question_id'); 
}
```

AnswerController

```
public function index($question_id){
  $answers = Answer::orderBy('id')->where('question_id', $question_id)->get()
  return $answers;
}
```

And the view

```
@foreach($answers as $answer)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $answer->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $answer->description }}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

When he inspected the foreache he threw this at me

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Descripcion</th>
        <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Descripcion suprema</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please use inspect element on the foreach and paste us the results.

Comment: what do you mean? I paste what comes out of a dd ()?

Comment: Navigate to foreach  tag in your html page(where your are passing the question id to controller). right click -> inspect element.. The code will be now visible.. Try to find if the id is same or different in the foreach

Comment: The id in the foreach is the same as, in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is defined with 2 parameters in it:

```
exams/{exam}/questions/{question}/answers
```

The **first** for `exam` and the **second** for `question`.

Your Controller method only takes 1 parameter, so it will only receive the **first** route parameter which would be for `exam`.

> "Route parameters are injected into route callbacks / controllers based on their order - the names of the callback / controller arguments do not matter." - [Laravel 7.x Docs - Routing - Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-parameters)

You would need to have a **second** argument for this method to receive the **second** parameter:

```
public function index($exam_id, $question_id)
```

If you don't add a second argument you would have to get the parameter by name from the Request:

```
Request::route('question')
```

Comment: Right, I forgot to add the definition of the routes. In a moment I add them.

Comment: that is always good to have ... the issue is as described above, you are not taking an argument for the route parameter you need

Comment: From what you say, the parameter I need is exam, since question has the id = 1, therefore, the id never changes ... right?

Comment: you seem to want the question id based on what you are doing in your controller method `where('question_id', ...)` ... so the exam id wont help you ... you need to take 2 arguments if you want the question id to be passed to your controller method